# Problems understanding preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to be able to search for a specific code (up to three letters) that have been previously capitalized by strtoupper() to ensure correctness. I would like the search to look for the first character to be a "C" and then the last character(s) to be one of the following: L, M, P, C, BC, or RC. Therefore I am actually looking to search for CL, CM, CP, CC, CBC, or CRC.

I have the following:

```
// Make sure designation code is entered
   if (empty($designation)) {
     echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code is required</p>";
     $valid = false; }
// Make sure designation code is not too long (3 characters)
   if (strlen($designation)>3) {
     echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code cannot be more than 3 characters</p>";
  $valid = false; }
// Convert designation code to all uppercase
   $designation = strtoupper($designation);
// Make sure designation code is valid
   if (preg_match("/(CL|CM|CP|CC|CBC|CRC)/",$designation))  {
     echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct</p>";
     $valid = false; }
```

Everything works up to `preg_match()`; that's where nothing happens. I can type any letter and it will accept it as valid.

I also tried the following, but I just don't think this is correct:

```
if (preg_match("/^C[L|M|P|C|BC|CR]/",$designation)){
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct</p>";
    $valid = false; }
```

Comment: 1. Try [Regexp Online tester](http://regexpal.com/) to try regexps online. You will easyly find any mistake.

2. Additionally, you don't need to strtoupper. Add «i» option to your regexp. `preg_match("/(CL|CM|CP|CC|CBC|CRC)/i",$designation)`

Comment: Why do you even need regexp for this? Can't you do sth like `$valid = array("CL, "CM", ...); if (in_array($designation, $valid)) { ...`?

Comment: The options I am searching for come from user input in a form.  I want to make sure that the code is valid only from the list mentioned above.

Comment: As a side note, are you sure that you want to throw an error when match is found? Maybe you should throw it when it's not found? if ( !preg_match()) ?

Comment: To be little more clear...

I am taking information from a form and making sure that it is correct before it is added to a database; hence strtoupper().  The $valid starts out as true and it is tested on all entries to make sure everything is correct.  If at any point, it becomes false the user is instructed to return to the original page and correct the error(s).

Once I get to this part I am using a regexp to make sure that the code entered is valid and only from one of the approved codes.  If the code matches, it should keep going.  If not, then an error should be returned.

Comment: This code: "if (preg_match("/(CL|CM|CP|CC|CBC|CRC)/",$designation))  {
     echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:" means: if there is for example CL entered, throw error. If there is any other letter - continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.  With all the input I was able to understand what was going on.  As for my code the following works perfectly:

```
if (!preg_match('/C(L|M|P|C|BC|RC)/',$designation)) {
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct;
$valid = false;
```

Making preg_match() look for something other than what is in the list is what I was missing.  This looks for the first letter of the code to be "C" and the rest to be one of the choices in the list.  Additionally, I did not require `i` to ignore case because I already used `strtoupper()` to capitalize any input for this field.  Now, if anything not in the list is entered the error message is displayed.

Comment: So which of the answers helped you most? I'd say Ed Cottrell's. Accept it then

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
if (preg_match("/(C(L|M|P|C|BC|RC))/i",$designation)) {
     echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct</p>";
$valid = false; 
}
```

the fact is, if you're looking for an entire text, you will need preg_match_all since php doesnt support /g modifier

Answer (score 0):

Two important things.

The regexp part:

```
 /^C(L|M|P)/i
```

means 'match anything starting with C followed by L or M or P independent of case', the [] denote a range, not a set of alternatives

The php part:

preg_match returns 1 on match. 0 on non-match and false on error. Your test should look like this if you want to be unambiguous

```
if(preg_match($pattern,$subject) === 1)
{
}
```

In your code example, the following should work

```
 if (preg_match('/^C(L|M|P|C|BC|RC)/i',$designation) === 1)  
 {
      echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct</p>";
      $valid = false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, your logic is backwards. You want to accept it if the code is `CL`, etc., not reject it.  In other words, you should reject it only if the `preg_match()` returns false.  Just add a `!` before the call to `preg_match()` to reverse your `if` condition, like so:

```
// Make sure designation code is valid
if (!preg_match("/(CL|CM|CP|CC|CBC|CRC)/",$designation))  { //notice the ! inside the parentheses
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct</p>";
    $valid = false;
}
```

If I have misunderstood your requirements, please let me know.

Also, as others have pointed out, you can use the `i` flag to avoid the call to `strtoupper()`. If you want to accept only the codes you listed above and not, say, `FCL`, add `^` and `$` before and after the body of the regex, respectively. This also makes your strlen check unnecessary, unless you just want to show the error about the code length. This would make your entire code look like this:

```
// Make sure designation code is entered
if (empty($designation)) {
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code is required</p>";
    $valid = false;
}
// Make sure designation code is not too long (3 characters)
// NOTE: This block is now optional
if (strlen($designation)>3) {
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code cannot be more than 3 characters</p>";
    $valid = false;
}

// Make sure designation code is valid
if (!preg_match("/^(CL|CM|CP|CC|CBC|CRC)$/i",$designation))  { //notice the ! inside the parentheses
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR:  Designation code not correct</p>";
    $valid = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/^((CL)|(CM)|(CP)|(CC)|(CBC)|(CRC))/i
```

Try http://www.regexr.com/ to play with RegExps.
Option «i» means ignore case. No need to strtoupper.